# GA4 can't recognise URLs in foreign languages - What can be done?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We used to work a lot with Google analytics UA, we transferd to GA 4 and we came a cross a great difficulty with simplyfing data gathering due to utf-8 encoding in Landing pages report.
[encoded urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEN7L.png)
I have tried to find a solution, but it seems others who use foreign languages in their urls can't find a solution either. anybody got an idea how to solve this?

I have tried to use custom dimensions but I cant seem to understand how to replace the Landing-pages properly

Comment: You should use the encoded/decoded functions to send/recieve info from/to your GA Event. Html Entity Encode in PHP :
 $string = "Español";
$encodedString = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $encodedString;  // Displays: Espa&ntilde;ol
and decode : 
 $encodedString = "Espa&ntilde;ol";
$decodedString = html_entity_decode($encodedString, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo $decodedString;  // Displays: Español